# Question about partial derivative in the proof of the Poisson bracket of the Hamiltonian and a function of its flow

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, classical-mechanics

Let $M$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d$ such that the flow of the Hamiltonian maps $M$ to itself and $G_t$ be the flow map of the Hamiltonian i.e. $G_t(x_0,p_0) = (x(t),p(t))$ if $x(0)=x_0$ and $p(0)=p_0$. Now we let $f_t:= f\circ G_t$. Let $\mathcal{A}=C^\infty(M)$.

Then we have $\frac{d}{dt}f_t = \{H,f_t\},$ where $\{\cdot, \cdot\}: \mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{A}$ is given by

$$\{f,g\}:=\sum_{i=1}^d (\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_i}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial g}{\partial p_i}).$$

The proof proceeds as follows. Let $(x,p)\in M$ be given We denote by $(x(t),p(t))$ the solution of the Hamiltonian equation with initial data $(x,p)$. We compute, using the chain rule

$$\frac{d}{dt}f_t(x,p)=\frac{d}{dt}f(x(t),p(t))=\sum_{i=1}^d \big[ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x(t),p(t))\dot{x_i}(t)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_i}(x(t),p(t))\dot{p_i}(t)\big].$$

Since $(x(t),p(t))$ solves Hamilton's equation the above expression is
$$=\sum_{i=1}^d \big[\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_i} \frac{ \partial f}{\partial x_i}-\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_i}\big](x(t),p(t)) = \{H,f_t\}(x,p).$$

In the last expression of the proof, I am not sure why $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x(t),p(t))=\frac{\partial f_t}{\partial x_i}(x,p)$ and similarly for the partial derivative of $f_t$ with respect to $p_i$.

I am confused because $f_t=f\circ G_t$ so if we take the partial derivative of $f_t$ with respect to $x_i$ shouldn't we use the chain rule? From my understanding, the left side is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x(t),p(t))=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\circ G_t(x,p)?$ But how is this equal to $\frac{\partial f_t}{\partial x_i}(x,p)=\frac{\partial (f\circ G_t)}{\partial x_i}(x,p)?$ How do we just move $G_t$ inside the partial derivative?

Comment: It is indeed confusion as it is. So far, you have only shown that $df_t/dt = \{ H, f\}_t$. An important property of Hamiltonian dynamics is the fact that
$ \{f_t, g_t\} = \{f,g\}_t\,;$. This follows as $G_t$ is a canonical transformation (for any $t$) together with the fact that canonical transformation leave the Poisson bracket invariant.

Comment: @Fabian What is the definition of $\{\cdot ,\cdot \}_t$? And what do you mean by a canonical transformation? Also then is it not true that $d/dt f_t = \{H,f_t\}$?

Comment: Two things will clarify the matter: $\{f,g\}_t = \{f, g\}\circ G_t$. And $H_t = H$.

Comment: @Fabian Could you write a proof that $\{f,g\}\circ G_t =\{f_t,g_t\}$? And I guess $H_t = H$ because $H$ is invariant under a trajectory?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (I am not regularly checking the site). You should find the proof of the following 2 facts in any textbook: 1) canonical transformations leave the Poisson bracket invariant (sometimes this is even the def. of a canonical transformation). 2) the time evolution is a canonical transformation. See for example page 9 of [this](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahad0/7302_handout_12.pdf).